# I request Excel to find a sequence of word in a text string but it returns #VALUE or FALSE

Tags: excel, vba, text, excel-formula

In cell A1 there is a text string.

Formulas and macros work if I type the text into Cell A1. But if I copy the very same text from a PDF file or Notepad and paste into Cell A1, Formulas and macros won't work.

Before pasting the text string into Cell A1, I first copy the text from a PDF file and then paste it into Notepad. I then copy the text string from Notepad and paste it into Cell A1.

If I type the text, Formulas and macros works.
If I copy from Notepad (or even the pdf file) and paste it, I get #VALUE or FALSE.

Here is one formula that I use:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("customers' inventories in January is",A1))
```

which returns FALSE if I paste the text string, but returns TRUE if I type it.

and here is one macro: (which returns #VALUE if I paste the text string, but works if I type the text string into cell A1)

```
Function REPLACETEXTS(strInput As String, rngFind As Range, rngReplace As Range) As String
Dim strTemp As String
Dim strFind As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim cellFind As Range
Dim lngColFind As Long
Dim lngRowFind As Long
Dim lngRowReplace As Long
Dim lngColReplace As Long
lngColFind = rngFind.Columns.Count
lngRowFind = rngFind.Rows.Count
lngColReplace = rngFind.Columns.Count
lngRowReplace = rngFind.Rows.Count
strTemp = strInput
If Not ((lngColFind = lngColReplace) And (lngRowFind = lngRowReplace)) Then
REPLACETEXTS = CVErr(xlErrNA)
Exit Function
End If
For Each cellFind In rngFind
strFind = cellFind.Value
strReplace = rngReplace(cellFind.Row - rngFind.Row + 1, cellFind.Column - rngFind.Column + 1).Value
strTemp = Replace(strTemp, strFind, strReplace)
Next cellFind
REPLACETEXTS = strTempEnd Function
```

Comment: It may be because the pasted string has other characters surrounding it?
Perhaps you should use `strTemp = Trim(strInput)` at the start of your process to see if any additional whitespaces need to be removed?

Comment: Are the spaces actual ASCII 32 spaces? I got a feeling they may be ASCII 160, a non-breaking space. Depending on what you are comfortable with, you could use the notepad++ step in your process to transform your data and replace them with actual space characters.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion mtholen. As you suggested I changed ``` strTemp = strInput ``` to ``` strTemp = Trim(strInput) ``` but it didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Hi JvdV. Thanks for your time and help. I didn't know Notepad++. So I downloaded it, installed it and then I copied and pasted the text string. On the ribbon I clicked on "Search" then in the drop-down menu I clicked on Replace. In the Pop-up window, at "Find what": I entered      \d160      then next to "Replace with": I typed     \x20       then I let the box "Wrap around" checked (default setting) and selected "Extended (\n, \r, \t, \x...) then I pressed enter.  As resulted it turns out that all spaces were just regular spaces (ALT+32)... so it didn't solve the problem. :/

Comment: Please edit your question to show a concrete example of the text you're pasting (you can paste directly from the PDF into the post) and the worksheet formula you're using to call your UDF.   You might find it easier to debug if you call your function from a Sub instead of from a worksheet cell.

Comment: Hi Tim Williams. Thanks for your time. Here is the text from the PDF file:

Comment: ISM ’s Customers’ Inventories Index registered 33.1 percent in January, 4.8 percentage points lower than the 37.9 percent reported for December, indicating that customers’ inventory levels were considered too low. “Customers’ inventories are too low for the 54th consecutive month, a positive for future production growth. This is the lowest reading since December 2009 (32.5 percent), and for six months in a row, the Customers’ Inventories Index has been at its lowest levels since December 2009-June 2010, when it averaged 35.2 percent,” says Fiore.

Comment: Of the 18 industries, the only one reporting higher customers’ inventories in January is Printing & Related Support Activities. The 14 industries reporting customers’ inventories as too low during January — listed in order — are: Wood Products; Nonmetallic Mineral Products; Primary Metals; Machinery; Transportation Equipment; Furniture & Related Products; Fabricated Metal Products; Electrical Equipment, Appliances & Components; Plastics & Rubber Products; Paper Products; Chemical Products; Computer & Electronic Products; Food, Beverage & Tobacco Products; and Miscellaneous Manufacturing.

Comment: (so you can see that it is a pretty long text) , and  here is the formula I use to call my UDF : ``` =REPLACETEXTS(O1,Data!E1:E12,Data!F1:F12) ```  while in cell O1 there is the following formula:  ``` =TRIM(TEXTAFTER(A1,"says Fiore.")) ```

Comment: That seems to work OK for me, but without the original PDF to copy from I'm not sure I'm replicating your use case.

Comment: Thanks Tim Williams for your time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again thank you very much for your time! Actually I found the solution to my problem! There wasn't any problem with the macro or the formulas... the problem was that there was a mismatch between the text string I pasted and the text I typed in my formulas and macros.
for example when I pasted the following text string "... customers’ inventories ..."
it didn't match what I had either in my dataset, formulas when I typed "... customers' inventories ..." . Do you see the difference ? The difference lies between ' CHAR(39) and ’ CHAR(146). Because when I type on the keyboard I actually only use ' or CHAR(39)... I didn't visually see the difference between the two symbols...  Anyway, the problem is solved now and I can move on! :D Thanks again for your time.